# VSCodeでRubyを実行してもhello world が表示されない

Tags: ruby

VScodeでhello worldしたいのですがエラーがでます。ご教示よろしくお願いします。

環境： Windows 10, VScode

---

**hello.rb**

```
print "hello world!"
```

**表示されたエラー**

```
C:\Users\※※※※\Documents\Ruby>ruby hello.rb
'ruby' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
```

Comment: Ruby自体はインストールされていますか？[VSCodeで最低限のRuby環境構築 - 設定編](https://impsbl.hatenablog.jp/entry/RubyInVSCode1)

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 'ruby' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
>   操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。

ruby自体がインストールされていない場合は上記のエラーが出ます。
[VSCodeで最低限のRuby環境構築 - 設定編](https://impsbl.hatenablog.jp/entry/RubyInVSCode1)などを参考にしてセットアップを見直してみてください。

それでも動かない場合は[環境変数PATH](https://qiita.com/3no3_tw/items/8c0bcf258370d91bf6e0#%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83%E7%A2%BA%E8%AA%8D)が正しく記述されているかを確認してみてください。

各種リンク先については、Web検索して上位に表示された分かりやすいサイトをリンクさせていただきました。

Comment: 既にコメントの後に解決済みですが、若干加筆して回答としました。

Comment: 再度問題があれば参考にさせてもらいます。ありがとうございました。